# Twiiter Typeahead Custom Templates - Getting Default Example Working

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I am having trouble getting the default Twitter typeahead custom template working found here: http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/#custom-templates
I am able to get the default demo working just fine. 
Here is my js code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

var bestPictures = [
    {"year": "1996", "value": "Tom", "url": "http://example.com"},
    {"year": "1998", "value": "Tim", "url": "http://example.com"}
];


$('#custom-templates .typeahead').typeahead(null, {
  name: 'best-pictures',
  display: 'value',
  source: bestPictures,
  templates: {
    empty: [
      '<div class="empty-message">',
        'unable to find any Best Picture winners that match the current query',
      '</div>'
    ].join('\n'),
    suggestion: Handlebars.compile('<div><strong>{{value}}</strong> – {{year}}</div>')
  }
   });
});
```

I couldn't find the source code of the example in where they get `bestPictures` from. I also have handlebars installed. When I type in the letter `t` into the search box, my console log shows `this.source is not a function` in `typeahead.bundle.js` on this line: `this.source(query, sync, async);`

Additionally, I would like to do a redirect once a dropdown option is selected, similar to

```
on('typeahead:selected', function(event, datum) {
    window.location = datum.url
});
```

Comment: Which portion of `js` is not returning expected results ?

Comment: Well, the dropdown is not being populated. I am receiving an error inside of typeahead.js

Comment: Try using `Bloodhound` , passing `bestPicture` as object to `suggestion` function, see post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `Bloodhound` , returning object `bestPictures` as a property accessible at `.typeahead` `suggestions` function

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  var bestPictures = [{
    "year": "1996",
    "value": "Tom",
    "url": "http://example.com"
  }, {
    "year": "1998",
    "value": "Tim",
    "url": "http://example.com"
  }];

  var pictures = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace("value"),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    local: $.map(bestPictures, function(d) {
      return {
        value: d.value,
        // pass `bestPictures` to `suggestion`
        suggest: d
      }
    })
  });

  pictures.initialize();

  $("#custom-templates .typeahead").typeahead(null, {
    name: "best-pictures",
    display: "value",
    source: pictures.ttAdapter(),
    templates: {
      notFound: [
        "<div class=empty-message>",
        "unable to find any Best Picture winners that match the current query",
        "</div>"
      ].join("\n"),
      suggestion: function(data) {
        // `data` : `suggest` property of object passed at `Bloodhound`
        return "<div><strong>" + data.suggest.value + "</strong>" 
               + data.suggest.year + "</div>"
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/releases/latest/typeahead.bundle.js">
</script>

<div id="custom-templates">
  <input type="text" class="typeahead" placeholder="Best picture winners" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly!